# Rsync from local linux to remote windows server

Tags: rsync, sshpass, filecopy

I am trying to copy files from local Linux server to remote windows file server using rysnc and sshpass but getting error

code

```
rsync --rsh='/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'password' ssh -p 139 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l user' /x/y/z/ user@x.x.x.x:/a/b/c/
```

output

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have rsync installed on the WIndows machine?  It's not built-in.

Comment: can we install rsync in windows??

Comment: Of course, but there are other alternatives, like `scp` or using `samba` to mount a Windows file share on your Linux system.

Comment: i want to copy files without mounting the server

Comment: Why?  That is clearly the "Windows way" of handling this.

Comment: because after mounting, the folders has root as owner but I'm using Apache as user hence it is showing permission denied.

Comment: There are ways to deal with that.  Samba wouldn't be much good without it.  I'm just presenting another alternative.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450629/mounting-smb-shares-without-root-permission